# Why Cookies are not set in the browser but works in Postman?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

Backend is Spring boots. I setup cookie there and it is working fine with postman.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")

//Spring boots  (http://localhost:8080)
         Cookie cookie = new Cookie("access-token",token);
         cookie.setPath("/");
         cookie.setSecure(false);      
         response.addCookie(cookie);
          
         response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Front End is ReactJS, I've used a POST method using Axios to get Login information.
I am getting response, but cookies are not set.

```
//React JS (http://localhost:3000)
           axios({
                url: common.url + '/login',
                data: "userId=" + userid+ "&password=" + password,
                method: 'post',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache','withCredentials':'true'
                }
            }).then(function (result) {
                ;
               //Success Login
               
            })
```

Tried many things. No Luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a fix finally.

```
axios.post(url+'/login', { json }, { withCredentials: true }).then(function (result) {
}
```

WithCredentials should be passed like this from front-end.
in Backend code, along with the Crossorigin management, we need to add allowCredentials to true

Answer (score 1):

You need some more setup on the Cookie for it to work as what you expect

1. `cookie.setPath("/")` if you want it to be included in any requests.
2. If you are running your application in a `non-https` mode, you need to `cookie.setSecure(false)`, otherwise, the browser will just ignore it.
3. If you want the cookie to be `httpOnly`, do `cookie.setHttpOnly(true)`

There're plenty more setups but those three should give you a decent result

Comment: @Ngoc Hy
Did that too.. Still cookies are not showing. 
JavaSpring is running or localhost:8080 and react in localhost:3000.

Comment: if you're still dealing with this problem, try adding `credentials: 'include'` in your requests.